# Connect 200 Oculus Go to a single wireless router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, oculus-rift

How to broadcast real time data to 200 Oculus Go?

The sent data would be approximately 4800 bits of information, at least 25 times per seconds. All Oculus Go would receive the same data.

This seems unlikely to work properly with a single Wi-Fi router, [because of signal interference](https://www.lifewire.com/how-many-devices-can-share-a-wifi-network-818298).

Could it work using multiple wireless routers?

Or is there a way to broadcast Wi-Fi signal to many devices, all listening the same channel (setting the Oculus Go as passive receivers, and having a single emitter)?

Comment: 50 3D positions is entirely arbitrary. There is no information as to what bandwidth you'd need or the size of the data. Both of which could be relevant. A Wi-Fi signal is also always a broadcast you're probably thinking about multi cast or similar.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant 150 * 32 bits, 4800 bits of information, at least 25 times per seconds. By "broadcasting Wi-Fi signals using the Oculus Go as passive receivers", I meant emitting data from the wireless router, and only receiving on the Oculus Go (not answering nor anything else) all on the same channel (to avoid signal interference). I was advised to use a custom external board with an nRF24L01 2.4GHz Wireless Transceiver and an atmega32u4, if it is not possible to do this with the integrated Wi-Fi.

Comment: "150 * 32 bits, 4800 bits" - where did you get that? What's 150 and 32 bits?

Comment: This is a rough approximation, I just want to send about 50 3D positions, I don't really care how I encode the data but I just assumed it could be 150 floats (50 * 3 coordinates) represented with 32 bits.

Comment: Is it different data for each single Oculus Go, or the same data for each? Multicasting on wireless, even if encrypted via WPA/WPA2, sends the data only once, so if it's the same data, that should work out of the box without bandwidth trouble (provided you can convince the Oculus Go to receive multicast data).

Comment: Yes, it's the same data, sorry I didn't mention that. So how can I receive multicast data on Android devices? (maybe I'll create another question)

Comment: @arthur.sw you have the application on all the Androids listen to a **class-d IP Address** of your choosing. (If you are the author of said application).

Comment: Thanks dirkt and Tim_Stewart! I would accept your answers.